# Delete user from firebase authentication with angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

What is the best way to delete a user from Firebase's Authentication using Angular and the user's id or email? I can't find a relevant function in AngularFireAuth.auth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "pure" JavaScript you can do the following and user with mail user@mail.com will be deleted from the Authentication list.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("user@mail.com", "abcd")
.then(function (info) {
   var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   user.delete();
});
```

In angular2+ you can do something like below,

```
remove(user: any, path: string) { 
  return this.db.list(this.PATH + path).remove(user.key) .then(() => { 
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password) .then(function (info) { 
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
      user.delete(); 
    }); 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: This way requires the user's password, since the signInWithEmailAndPassword function will be called. Can i get it somehow?